# What is a good tag for the "where in the world can I" questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just asked a question on behalf of someone close to me who is trying to choose a place for the next family trip based on wanting to experience something specific. (In this case, it's seeing flowing lava, but it could be diving with sharks or seeing a polar bear or sleeping in a hammock in a rain forest or any of dozens of rare or rarish experiences that can only be found in a few places). I had trouble tagging it. Eventually I chose [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations). The aurora question has that tag. I think the "where should i see the eclipse from" question counts too, and probably many more. The key is that you want something unusual (warm water and beaches doesn't count) and that you don't much care whether you buy a plane ticket to South America or to Africa, as long as you get to see or do what it was you were after.

Is **Destinations** the right tag for this? Can we come up with something more exciting? How would **Where-In-The-World** do?

Comment: Did you see that? Jeff tweets the question and it goes from 150 views to 450 views in like 15 minutes. I may wait a few weeks and ask another one for someone else.

Comment: I don't like [tag:destinations]; too vague and open-ended. Even with a tag wiki excerpt, I wonder how many will *think* of typing in 'destinations' when they start typing a tag.

Comment: "Destinations" is vague and open ended when thought of for this purpose, but that's not it's purpose. "Destinations" is specifically for questions asking for help to choose between various destinations. Now it might be possible to come up with a better name for it, but it will be hard to come up with a perfectly intuitive name for it, as it will be for many tags here compared to SO.

Answer (score 5):

How about [where-on-earth](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/where-on-earth)?

Shorter, less hyphens and words, and a potential word play.

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: It's not bad. There are going to be plenty of times when naming a tag will be a lot harder here than on say Stack Overflow. And the more effort we make to work on tag excerpts and wikis and retagging, which we have been good at and improving, then working with such tags should be less of a problem.

Comment: I also think if we have some "hard to guess" tags like this, that it would be a perfect topic for a blog article about tagging.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

**Where can I**

A bit less intuitive than "where can I see" but also more flexible for when it's not really about seeing...

Comment: Too open-ended.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

**Where can I see**

Seems intuitive but sometimes it is about where but not about seeing...

Comment: You nailed it - can be things other than seeing.

Answer (score -2):

there is a [locate-this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locate-this) tag you could use...

Comment: I interpret that as "where is this specific thing I heard of / have a picture of" but I suppose it could be used for "where are opportunities to see/do something special"

Comment: Yes I agree with Kate, based on the wording of the "local this" tag. But maybe we could come up with a wording that works for both types of questions and is still useful for **characterising** questions.